# Zip folders and files recursivly SSH

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

I'm trying to make a script that will zip and download wordpress plugins from the staging environment via SSH and unpack them locally.

I am using PHPSecLib for this.

Now when i'm connected to the server and execute this command:

```
cd /path/to/wp-content/plugins && zip -r plugins.zip *
```

A file is indeed created, however it has no extension, and it has the wrong name.

When i try this:

```
cd /path/to/wp-content/plugins && zip plugins.zip *
```

a plugins.zip is created, with all the all the files and folders from the plugin directory, however every plugin folder is empty.

Some of the output i get when running the 1st command:

```
adding: wp-super-cache/languages/wp-super-cache-tr_TR.po (deflated 70%)
adding: wp-super-cache/languages/wp-super-cache-zh_CN.mo (deflated 61%)
adding: wp-super-cache/languages/wp-super-cache-ru_RU.po (deflated 72%)
```

About every file shows up in the output.

Could someone point me into the right direction ?

Comment: Be careful - when is the glob being expanded?

Comment: I'm sorry, i have no idea what that means.

Comment: `*` is a glob - it gets expanded *before* the command is actually executed.

Comment: I removed the * and it now works like a charm. Please make an answer, and i'll accept ;), and if you can, explain the glob thingy ;)